# Eigenvalues of the Hessian of a strictly convex function $F:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}\in C^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis, positive-definite

In Chapter 1 of "Direct Methods in the Calculus of Variations", Giusti writes:

"For the sake of simplicity, we shall write $A^{ij}(z)$ instead of $F_{z_i z_j}(z)$. Since $F$ is a convex function, the matrix $A^{ij}$ is positive semi-definite; moreover if we assume, as we shall always do, that $F$ is strictly convex, we will have for every $\zeta \in \mathbb{R}^n$:

$$\lambda(z) \lvert \zeta\rvert^2 \leq A^{i}(z)\zeta_i \zeta_j \leq \Lambda(z) \lvert \zeta\rvert^2,$$
where $\Lambda(z)$ and $\lambda(z) >0$ are respectively, the largest and the smallest eigenvalues of the matrix $A(z)$."

What I don't understand here is why $\lambda(z)>0$ has to hold. This implies that all eigenvalues of $A(z)$ are positive, which is equivalent to the fact that $A(z)$ is positive definit. However, a strictly convex function doesn't necessarily have a positive definit Hessian. While talking about this chapter in class, our professor explicitly required that $A(z)$ is positive definit, which implies strict convexity. So am I missing something or is there a mistake?

Comment: Huh...you know I never thought about these two things *not* being equivalent, but the examples are obvious ($x^4$ for instance). I wonder if there's any issue if every time they write "strictly convex" it's interpreted as "positive Hessian".

Comment: My best guess is that it is an *assumption*, e.g. they consider only "good" strictly convex functions with $\lambda(z)>0$.